# display data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a problem in showing data coming from database sqlite, i looked for a solution

here i did found plenty but i couldn't make it work, the error i get is : Error occured:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist !!

my code is :

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER = 2;
private Cursor cursor;
private ArrayList<String> arr;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
Cursor c;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        db.open();
        Button suivant = (Button)findViewById(R.id.com_quest);

        suivant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent l = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityUn.class);
            startActivity(l);

        }
        });

        populateListViewFromDB();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Error occured: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void populateListViewFromDB() {
Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

Log.i("MyApp", "Total users: " + cursor.getCount());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Number of rows: " + cursor.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();

String[] databaseColumnNames = new String[] { DBAdapter._id };
int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.text };

SimpleCursorAdapter myCursordapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main, cursor, databaseColumnNames, toViewIDs,FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

list.setAdapter(myCursordapter);
         }  }
```

and in dbadapter is :

```
   private static final String MENAGE = "table_MENAGE";

   public static final String _id = "Num_du_Questionnaire";

     public Cursor getAllRecords() {
     return db.query(MENAGE, new String[] { _id
             }, null, null, null,
             null, null);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [`CursorAdapter`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) require that the `Cursor` includes a column called `_id`. Your `Cursor` contains just one column called `Num_du_Questionnaire`.

Comment: thanks for responding :), i know that, that's why i name it _id !! so i will replace Num_du_Questionnaire by _id , and tell you result.

Comment: @UtmanAlami Your Java variable name is not the same as SQL column name (which in your code is the value of that variable).

Comment: yes it works, but it appears only one row, and i have ten in my database, why ??